# Get value from a link to display a <div> in the same page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a `<table>` in my Research.php page like that

---

### | Date | User| Group | ETC |

The column `Date` is a link. Here is a sample of the `<table>` creation :

```
while($line= mysqli_fetch_array($warning))
{
echo "<tr>";
    echo"<td ><a href=\"\" onclick=\"javascript:visibilite('Details'); return false;\">".date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($line['Date_heure']))."</a></td>";
```

The javascript code :

```
<script>
        function visibilite(thingId)
        {
            var targetElement;
            targetElement = document.getElementById(thingId) ;
            if (targetElement.style.display == "none")
            {
                targetElement.style.display = "" ;
            } else {
                targetElement.style.display = "none" ;
            }
        }
        </script>
```

And the `<div>` placed in the same page:

```
<div id="Details" style="display:none;">
```

Everything work well. My problem is that I want the `div#Details` to change according to the date clicked. What my code do is that it hides the `div#Details` but display the same informations. I want to be able to get the value clicked to change `div#Details` according to the data in my db.
I tried to add in the `<a>` `href='Research.php?Number=".$line['Number']."'` but nothing happens when I click a link.

I don't know if i have to use JQuery and how, or if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: nothing happens because of `return false`

Comment: If i dont write `return false;` the div doesn't stay at the screen, the div is displayed only when i click on the link. If i release the mouse it disappears

Comment: `return false` causes that link will not open href on click, empty href cause reload of page, thats why your div disappears, instead of empty href is better to use hash `href="#"`

Comment: Yes you're right, thank you :D This is absolutely what I wanted !
The `return false;` made it not working

Comment: @Pepo_rasta how to prevent the div from disappearing ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 function visibilite(thingId)
        {
            var targetElement;
            targetElement = document.getElementById(thingId) ;
            if (targetElement.style.display == "none")
            {
                targetElement.style.display = "block" ;
            } else {
                targetElement.style.display = "none" ;
            }
        }
```

just replace "" with block and it will start working

Comment: The problem is that i want to get the value from the link.. this is my problem

Answer (score 0):

if you want display means using block

```
<script>

function visibilite(thingId)
        {
            var targetElement;
            targetElement = document.getElementById(thingId) ;
            if (targetElement.style.display == "none")
            {
                targetElement.style.display = "block" ;
            } else {
                targetElement.style.display = "none" ;
            }
        }
                </script>
```